# Sql avg using query

Tags: sql, average

My question today goes like this:

How many customers are above average?
I replied that way but it's wrong

```
select avg(height), count(*) as numofppl
from client
group by height
having height > avg(height)
```

Someone can offer a different solution(who work:))

Comment: With SQL questions please always tag the DBMS you are using. A solution for MySQL can be different from the solution for SQL Server for instance.

Answer (score 2):

```
select count(*) as numofppl
from client
where height > ( select avg(height) from client )
```

Comment: thx you very much

Comment: another question...  Write a query that reveals the names of the people whose height is greater than the average height of their species.

Comment: select * 
from client
where height > ( select avg(height) from client )

Comment: It does not work because you calculate the average of everyone and the question said that we have  to calculate the average of men separately and women separately

Answer (score 0):

try this query

`count(*)` count all the customer who `height > avg height`

```
select count(*) as numofppl from client where height > ( select avg(height) from client )
```

Comment: why down voted?

Comment: It wasn't me but it might be because someone else posted the same answer 2 minutes earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You group by height. So you get one row for height 100, one for height 200, etc. Now you ask what the avarage per group is, but all records of group height 100 have height = 100, so the avarage is 100 of course. `having height > avg(height)` is simply `having height > height` in your query, because of `group by height`.

What you want to compare with however is not the avarage per height, but the total avarage: no `GROUP BY` hence:

```
select count(*) 
from client
where height > (select avg(height) from client);
```

If you want to display the avarage height along, join it:

```
select x.avg_height, count(*)
from client c
cross join (select avg(height) as avg_height from client) x
where c.height > x.avg_height;
```

(Depending on the DBMS you may have to use an aggregate function on `x.avg_height`, e.g. `select max(x.avg_height)`.)